# Universal apollo-client for Angualr, React, React-Native

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-angular

Hi Stack Overflow community:

I'm looking into building a library that talks to a GraphQL server, get some data and do some transformation. I have customers who wants to use this library, but they are using different JS framework/library - Angular, React/React-Native.

So ideally, I only want to use *one package* for all customers(I'm fairly new to Angular and apollo).

Here is my confusion:

```
There are two libraries I'm investigating: 
1. apollo-client for react/react-native
2. apollo-angular for angular
```

I'm briefly looked at both, and I found `apollo-client` is a core package with lazy loading of react components.

While `apollo-angular` depends on `apollo-client` and provide angular related [`Link`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/tree/master/packages) and stuff.

**Question One**

I'm confused why Angular needs its specific Links and cache? Can't Angular simply use the [regular ones](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages).

**Question Two**

Seems like I have to do two packages(one react users and one for Angular users)? Any way to just use core `apollo-client` and build for all JS users?